# How to gather every 4 columns, but variables may have different length

Tags: r, data-cleaning, reshape2

I have a data frame that is organized with 4 columns that repeats 145. The length of the columns are not the same.

I would like reshape the data frame so that I have just 4 columns. I also have to spread some data.

Here is an example of what my data looks like:

```
df<- data.frame(
  id = c(rep("M",8), rep(NA, 2)),
  day =c(rep(seq(1:4),2), rep(NA,2)),
  parameter= c(rep("glu",4), rep("lac",4), rep(NA,2)),
  value = c(rep(2,4), rep(0.5,4), rep(NA,2)),
  id1 =c(rep("v",10)),
  day1= c(rep(1,5), rep(2,3), rep(1,2)), 
  parameter1 = c(rep("glu", 8), rep("lac", 2)),
  value1 = c(rep(2,8), rep(5,2)))
```

This is the result I want:

```
ideal.df<-data.frame(id =c(rep("M",10), rep("v", 10)),
                     day = c(rep(seq(1:4),2), rep(NA,2), rep(1,5), rep(2,3), rep(1,2)),
                     glu = c(rep(2,4), rep(NA,6), rep(1,8), rep(NA,2) ),
                     lac = c( rep(0.5,4), rep(NA,6),rep(5,2), rep(NA,8))
                     )
```

Comment: It is not clear  how you go from `df` to `ideal.df` even by looking at your example. What is the rule/algorithm to make the data transformation? Once this is clear it will be a lot easier to get the computer to do it for you :-) E.g. how is it decided that the result has 10 M values when the input only has 8? How does the `glu` value become 1 in row 11-18 when the input appears to have 2? Etc.

Comment: I would like to have every ID in the same columns (not multiple columns of ID1,ID2, etc...). Every parameter should be a column (but they don't have the same length -  that's why a put NA in my example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expected output seems very strange. Below is some very ugly example code to generate a result that seems more logical,
but apparently isn’t what the OP wants. Could the OP please explain why the result should be as posted (`ideal.df`) rather
than what is shown here (`df2`)?

Given data:

```r
df<- data.frame(
  id = c(rep("M",8), rep(NA, 2)),
  day =c(rep(seq(1:4),2), rep(NA,2)),
  parameter= c(rep("glu",4), rep("lac",4), rep(NA,2)),
  value = c(rep(2,4), rep(0.5,4), rep(NA,2)),
  id1 =c(rep("v",10)),
  day1= c(rep(1,5), rep(2,3), rep(1,2)), 
  parameter1 = c(rep("glu", 8), rep("lac", 2)),
  value1 = c(rep(2,8), rep(5,2)))
df
#>      id day parameter value id1 day1 parameter1 value1
#> 1     M   1       glu   2.0   v    1        glu      2
#> 2     M   2       glu   2.0   v    1        glu      2
#> 3     M   3       glu   2.0   v    1        glu      2
#> 4     M   4       glu   2.0   v    1        glu      2
#> 5     M   1       lac   0.5   v    1        glu      2
#> 6     M   2       lac   0.5   v    2        glu      2
#> 7     M   3       lac   0.5   v    2        glu      2
#> 8     M   4       lac   0.5   v    2        glu      2
#> 9  <NA>  NA      <NA>    NA   v    1        lac      5
#> 10 <NA>  NA      <NA>    NA   v    1        lac      5
```

Result of simple processing of the data:

```r
df2 <- data.frame(id = c(df$id, df$id1), day = c(df$day, df$day1))
df2$glu <- c(ifelse(df$parameter=="glu",df$value,NA), ifelse(df$parameter1=="glu",df$value1,NA))
df2$lac <- c(ifelse(df$parameter=="lac",df$value,NA), ifelse(df$parameter1=="lac",df$value1,NA))
df2
#>    id day glu lac
#> 1   1   1   2  NA
#> 2   1   2   2  NA
#> 3   1   3   2  NA
#> 4   1   4   2  NA
#> 5   1   1  NA 0.5
#> 6   1   2  NA 0.5
#> 7   1   3  NA 0.5
#> 8   1   4  NA 0.5
#> 9  NA  NA  NA  NA
#> 10 NA  NA  NA  NA
#> 11  1   1   2  NA
#> 12  1   1   2  NA
#> 13  1   1   2  NA
#> 14  1   1   2  NA
#> 15  1   1   2  NA
#> 16  1   2   2  NA
#> 17  1   2   2  NA
#> 18  1   2   2  NA
#> 19  1   1  NA 5.0
#> 20  1   1  NA 5.0
```

Desired result:

```r
ideal.df<-data.frame(id =c(rep("M",10), rep("v", 10)),
                     day = c(rep(seq(1:4),2), rep(NA,2), rep(1,5), rep(2,3), rep(1,2)),
                     glu = c(rep(2,4), rep(NA,6), rep(1,8), rep(NA,2) ),
                     lac = c( rep(0.5,4), rep(NA,6),rep(5,2), rep(NA,8))
)
ideal.df
#>    id day glu lac
#> 1   M   1   2 0.5
#> 2   M   2   2 0.5
#> 3   M   3   2 0.5
#> 4   M   4   2 0.5
#> 5   M   1  NA  NA
#> 6   M   2  NA  NA
#> 7   M   3  NA  NA
#> 8   M   4  NA  NA
#> 9   M  NA  NA  NA
#> 10  M  NA  NA  NA
#> 11  v   1   1 5.0
#> 12  v   1   1 5.0
#> 13  v   1   1  NA
#> 14  v   1   1  NA
#> 15  v   1   1  NA
#> 16  v   2   1  NA
#> 17  v   2   1  NA
#> 18  v   2   1  NA
#> 19  v   1  NA  NA
#> 20  v   1  NA  NA
```

Comment: Thank you!!! But since I had very long data.frame I wanted a cleaner way to do it. I'll do what you suggested, but first I'll do like this: require(data.table)
melt(setDT(df), id=1L,
     measure=patterns("^id", "^parameter", "^value"), 
     value.name=c("id", "parameter", "value"))